# transform list to list of maps in Groovy

Tags: json, list, groovy, hashmap

Can anyone help to convert a list to list of Maps in Groovy ?

I have a list as below

```
[war, jar]
```

and a variable with name `"value" = 2.0.0`

I want to convert this into a list with maps `[["pack": "war", "ver": "2.0.0"],["pack": jar, "ver": "2.0.0"]]`

and create a json.

```
{
    "ProjectId": "Projects-16",
    "ChannelId": "Channels-41",
    "Version": "2.0.1.0-10",
    "selectedPackages": [{"pack": "war", "ver": "2.0.0"}, {"pack": jar, "ver": "2.0.0"]}]
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it. Have you tried
`collect` or `collectEntries`?

Comment: Also `["war": "2.0.0", "jar": "2.0.0"]` is not the same as `[{"war": "2.0.0"}, {"jar": "2.0.0"}]`

Comment: yes. I tired `collect` and able to form `["war": "2.0.0", "jar": "2.0.0"]` but i'm not sure how i can convert everything into json.

Comment: Then why is your question phrased like you have problems building a map/list of maps, when your actual problem is something different? Have you looked into `JsonOutput` to create JSON?

Comment: Because, i'm not sure if the map I created is correct or not. As you pointed out `["war": "2.0.0", "jar": "2.0.0"]` is not the same as `[{"war": "2.0.0"}, {"jar": "2.0.0"}]`.  I also tried `list.collect { it ->     "{$it: ${value}}" }` which gives `[{jar: 4.0}, {war: 4.0}]`. But when i used `JsonBuilder` to convert into json, it converts as  `{
    "channelId": "Channels-41",
    "selectedPackages": [
        "war: 2.0.0.","jar:2.0.0"
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0.7-10",
    "projectId": "Projects-16"
}`

Comment: Please edit the question and put your actual problem in there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def packages = ["war", "jar"]
def value = "2.0.0"
def list = packages.collect { [pack : it, ver : value] }
def object = [
    ProjectId: "Projects-16",
    ChannelId: "Channels-41",
    Version: "2.0.1.0-10",
    selectedPackages: list
]
def json = JsonOutput.toJson(object)
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
```

Each `{}` entity in JSON is a map in Groovy therefore the expected `[{}, {}]` is a list of maps. You need just to construct the right objects using collect with the right transformation.

**Edit**
I updated the solution to return the exact json output as desired using a list and the variable `value`.

The output is this:

```json
{
    "ProjectId": "Projects-16",
    "ChannelId": "Channels-41",
    "Version": "2.0.1.0-10",
    "selectedPackages": [
        {
            "pack": "war",
            "ver": "2.0.0"
        },
        {
            "pack": "jar",
            "ver": "2.0.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's no problem here, but GStrings make bad map keys. Better use `[(it): ...]` instead.